# Masking of name related issue in sas

Tags: sql

I need to do masking of my data in order to hide it from the target audience.
Please find below existing table that I have right now. There are 3 columns in that table.

```
SNO FIRSTNAME LASTNAME 
1   JAYVADAN  DARJI
2   KAPIL     CHAUDHARY
```

In the desired output, I want 4 columns with masking done as below. MASKED_NAME column would be an addition column  the desired output.

The desired output that I want

```
SNO FIRSTNAME LASTNAME   MASKED_NAME 
1   JAYVADAN  DARJI      JXXXXXXN DXXXI
2   KAPIL     CHAUDHARY  KXXXL CXXXXXXXY
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags (and enterprise guide).  Please tag only with the tool you are really using.

Comment: What have you attempted? Tag with the appropriate database platform also

Comment: i have created this dataset in base sas enterprise guide. Please help me out with the code using base sas eg